# Feynman integrals in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

In quantum field theory, multi-loop Feynman integrals are basic ingredients of calculating high order corrections. Recently, I have come across the paper [A Feynman integral via higher normal functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2664). It seems that Feynman integrals have some relations to algebraic geometry. Since I am physics-oriented, I don't know much about algebraic geometry. Could anyone provide some explanations or expository articles on this topic? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is somewhat of a borderline question for the forum.  Generally "tell me about stuff" requests don't do very well.  It might make sense to start a meta thread where you could refine your question beforehand.

Comment: I think that Ryan has a point, although I'd be very interested in what answers show up!

Comment: You should look at the book "Feynman motives" by Marcolli.

Comment: @DanPetersen: To me, having seen your MO activity, it would be great to read any comments you could give on the subject.

Comment: @user125763 I'm flattered, but I don't think I have much useful to say about this circle of ideas. (And the question is in any case closed!)

Comment: @DanPetersen: \sadfaceemoticon

Comment: see http://www.physicsoverflow.org/23192/ for an answer.